# When and how (why) did the idea that gender is not biological start

Tags: language, sex

In my understanding the gender originally was based on the organs, there was cross dressing  but it was considered a man dressing as a woman.
And latter this changed and gender became something spiritual.

Am I correct?
If not then what is the history of gender?
If yes then
When and how (why) did the this change

> the state of being male or female (**typically used with reference to social and cultural differences rather than biological ones**).

At stop being biological (organs)?

---

Is it connected with "homosexually" stopped defining the way a person acts and became a way people define themselves (ie that they are born with these tendencies)

---

In other words what is the history of queer theory? (How old it is?)

Comment: Please edit the question to make it correct for this site, I am interested in the answer (and proofs) and the wording of my question is not important to me

Comment: I doubt that anyone ever stated seriously such a crazy idea, so the question makes no sense.

Comment: My doubts with this question is that it implies that, from the very beginnings of any society, there will be a social differentation based in gender. While it is difficult to prove or disprove (typical paleolithic nomad groups did not left many documents to study), it is an assumption too much restrictive to be comfortable with. Anyone can give some insights about that issue?

Comment: Additionally, (although slightly off-topic) current research shows that gender identity is mainly based in biological (genetical) circunstances (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_identity#Factors_influencing_formation). That would mean that gender is still biologically based, the difference nowadays being that mismatched sexual attributes or organs can be corrected in the same way that, say, a sixth finger in a hand is.

Comment: @SJuan76 thank you for your points, but a sixth finger to me is more like if the organs are of an androginus,

Comment: I'm conflicted wether this is a historical question or a sociel sciences question. You may also confuse the sex-gender distinction common in gender studies with Judith Butlers assertion that biological sex is also socially constructed. Voting to close for now as it's unclear what you are asking, likely due to lack of prior research. I think reading wiki about gender studies and queer theory would be a start.

Comment: Could the close voters explain their thinking? This question seems perfectly valid

Comment: This question shows very little research and lots of of spurious discussion of non-history topics. I would recommend (1) doing a couple of google searches - I think you'll find lots of evidence that binary gender is not universal and not modern, and (2) stripping discussion out of the question and focus on the history of gender identity. ("queer theory" is a different concept).

Comment: Well, there are different historical view. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-Spirit

Comment: I think one of the problems is that the question is based on the assumption that gender was "originally" thought of one way, which is not the case (unless they have a different connotation for "originally").  If that is not the case, they ask "what is the history of gender" which is obviously far too big a question for any SE site.

Comment: @rougon would that not be an answer that gender was always something spiritual and nothing to do with organs

Comment: @hazoriz no, it wouldn't. Gender is complicated and is--and has been--seen differently by different people. It's unclear to me whether you are meaning sex or gender, which are different. Sorry you're not getting answers here but this might be solved by some Wikipedia reading.

Comment: @rougon was it always complicated or only recently?

Comment: I think you should do some looking around first.  The wikipedia page for Sex and Gender distinction is a very good place to start.  It's a complicated question historically, because there have been lots of peoples, social groups, and cultures who have had different takes on this question.  It's also a question of terminology.  People spend their whole careers on these questions, so it's not something that's going to be answered here (unless you make you question much more specific).